# ReactJS componentWillUnmount not called on route change

Tags: reactjs

I am using the excellent create-react-app tool to build an app. My problem is as trivial as the title suggests but I cannot fix it. I have published a bare-bones app on github to illustrate:

https://github.com/diarmuidoconnor/reactdemo

The relevant excerpts from it are as follows.

The routing config is:

```
     <Router history={browserHistory} >
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
           <IndexRoute component={Foo}/>
           <Route path="bar" component={Bar} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
```

The Bar component code is:

```
 var Bar = React.createClass({
      componentWillUnmount: function() {
         localStorage.setItem('view', 2) ;
      },
      componentWillMount: function() {
           console.log('mounting') ;
          localStorage.setItem('view', 1) ;

       },

    render: function(){
         return (  
          <div>
            <h1>Bar </h1>
          </div>
        );
    }
  });
```

As you can see, it has componentWillMount and componentWillUnmount lifecycle methods. The former is called when I navigate to /bar (localStorage has the correct value, 1, for view key) but the latter is not when I move to a different URL (/) - localStorage value for the view key has not changed to 2, as I expected. It is still at 1.

My Environment

- OSX 10.9
- node v4.2.2
- npm 2.14.7
- Chrome Version 53.0.2785.143

Comment: Please have a look at [ask]. On [so] we don't write obvious things as they aren't needed. We know that you will appreciate any guidance and that you're thankful. It's reduntant.

Comment: Thanks Venugopal, your answer was correct. However, is their a slight inconsistency in React's design, as in, when you **manually** navigate to a URL the componentWillMount  of the newly mounted components **are callee** but the componentWillUnmount of the unmounted components are not called.

Comment: @Diarmuid that's the point. you can accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are changing the url manually to navigate between the routes. By doing that you won't see what you want to achieve. you have to do it by application navigation.

Add a header with those two links(App and Bar) and navigate using react's "Link".

but here I'm just adding a link to home page in bar page.

```
import React from 'react';
import { IndexLink } from 'react-router';

var Bar = React.createClass({
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        console.log('unmounting') ;
        localStorage.setItem('view', 2) ;
    },
    componentWillMount: function() {
        console.log('mounting') ;
        localStorage.setItem('view', 1) ;
     },
     render: function(){
         return (
             <div>
             <h1>Bar </h1>
             <IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</IndexLink>
         </div>
     );
  }
});

export default Bar;
```

This is enough to check 'componentWillUnmout' functionality.

Comment: I confirm that React unmount only when changing state with routers tags/API

Answer (score 2):

componentWillUnmount function is called when a component no longer required, if you change the route and the component is required on new route too, then it will not un-mount.

if you directly load a page or use anchor tag instead of Link, it will load a fresh page so no un-mounting required as its equivalent to opening page first time.

Now in your case  i don't see any **Link component** so you must be opening URL directly hence no un-mounting required

Comment: @luboskrnac which part ?